# Change character column dd/mm/yyyy to date column dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: r

I have a character column read in from a csv in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, with some blank rows being read in as `na`. I wish to convert this to a date column and maintain the `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```
df$Date <- strftime(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The above line causes the date to be gibberish. An example output is `20/06/0029` I think this is the **first two digits of the year/mm/00dd**

```
df<- transform(df, Date = chron(Start Date, format = "d/m/Y"))
```

The above using the chron package gives me `dd/mm/yy` but I can't adjust it to be `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The above line returns `yyyy-mm-dd`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at `format` where you can define how a *Date* should look like in output.

Comment: Date class can have only one form (`YYYY-MM-DD`), any other form would be of type character.

Comment: e.g.: `x <- as.Date("29/06/2000", "%d/%m/%Y")` and `format(x, "%d/%m/%Y")`.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for that information. Is there any way around this? I am building an RShiny app for a UK client. They are used to seeing dd/mm/yyyy. I wish to show this format in a drop down selector.

Comment: @GKi that is great and works perfectly. The `format(x, "%d/%m/%Y")` portion converts back to a character however. I wish to maintain the `dd/mm/yyyy` format but keep it in a date format as I need to sort chronologically in a drop down selector in RShiny

Comment: You can sort the *Date* but use `format` when you make an output.

Comment: It depends on that you want to do with the data. Sorting works on date and you just manipulate while it is in that form (doing stats, calcuating means etc.) but when you present the results you can convert it to a string. You can use that for plotting or whatever it is you wan to do.

Comment: Put the formatted vector into an additional column and subset for printing in shiny. The only other option would be a custom S3 class with its own print and format methods. Otherwise, the POSIXt methods display in standard format.

Comment: @GKi that's not a bad idea. I have several date columns in fact so it may be a little trickier but this is a good approach.

Comment: Thanks @Roland As other users have suggested, I will probably just manipulate the date as I need and display the output sorted and formatted.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
# Source string 
today <- "02/03/2021"

# Converted
today_as_date <- as.Date(today, format = "%d/%m/%Y") 

# Convert back to character
strftime(today_as_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```